# Thymeleaf Nested Modal Variables

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Thymeleaf for templating. I want to use the nested modal varabiles, but when I use it in nested form. I'm getting the follwing error,

th:text=${${FIELD_NAME_1}}

SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'

This is my template snippet,

```
                                        <!-- 
                                        <td th:href="@{'${URL}' + ${ID_FIELD}}"
th:text="${FIELD_NAME_1}">Tiger Nixon</td>
 -->
                                        <!-- <td th:text="${__${FIELD_NAME_1}__}">Tiger Nixon</td> -->
                                        <td th:text="${(country.countryName != null) ? ${country.countryName} : "nullvalue" }">Tiger Nixon</td> 
                                        <td th:text="${__${FIELD_NAME_2}__}">Lorem Ipsum is simply
                                            dummy text of the printing and type setting industry.</td>
                                        <td>Code not added</td>
                                        <td class="text-center"><span
                                            class="icon-edit float-left actionCircle"
                                            style="padding: 10px"></span>
                                            <div class="dotMenus mt-2 float-left">
                                                <span class="icon-Dots actionCircle"
                                                    style="padding: 10px 10px;"></span>
                                                <div class="dotMoreMenu mt-3">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#"> <span class="icon-Delete mr-2"></span>Delete
                                                        </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-lock mr-2"></i>Option
                                                                01
                                                        </a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-lock mr-2"></i>Option
                                                                02
                                                        </a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
```

These are my modal Varaibles,
modalAndView.addObject("COUNTRYS_DTOS", countrysFetchByPageResponseDto.getCountrys());
modalAndView.addObject("ITEM_DTO", "country");
modalAndView.addObject("ITEM_DTOS", "COUNTRY_DTOS");
modalAndView.addObject("FIELD_NAME_1", "country.countryName");
modalAndView.addObject("FIELD_NAME_2", "country.description");
But still it is generating a blank page.

Comment: Are you looking for preprocessing? `th:text="${__${FIELD_NAME_1}__}"`?

Comment: I want to use it with nested modal variables

Comment: There are no `modal` or `nested` variables in Thymeleaf -- I'm really not sure what you mean when you use those terms.  You can use preprocessing to evaluate a field to use it to look up another field, but other than that you can't nest `${...}` expressions.

Comment: This is my template snippet,